# Exporting Data into Access using C# simultaneously into two tables

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, insert

I'm trying to enter the id, first and last name into a table and then according to a combo box input I create another record right after that saves id of the student and the id of the Team which was chosen bu the combo box. Here is my code. everything runs well the only problem is that after that the record in the TeamPlayers table is not added. Please anyone ?!?

```
try
   {
      string team = null;

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=;Persist Security Info=False;"))
            {
                OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Students(BaruchID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES(@id, @first, @last)", conn);
                conn.Open();
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", tbBaruchID.Text);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", FirstName.Text);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", LastName.Text);
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/Users/Junglists/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/SACC_Baruch/SACC_Baruch/Teams.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"))
            {
                OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TeamNum FROM Teams WHERE TeamName='" + cbTeam.Text +"'", conn);
                conn.Open();
                OleDbDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);

                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    team = dr["TeamNum"].ToString();
                }
                conn.Close();
             }
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/Users/Junglists/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/SACC_Baruch/SACC_Baruch/Teams.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"))
            {
                OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO TeamPlayers(ID, BaruchID, TeamID) VALUES(@i, @id, @teamid)", conn);
                conn.Open();
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", 1);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", tbBaruchID.Text);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teamid", int.Parse(team));
                conn.Close();
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Student Added for team"+ cbTeam.Text);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

The parameter names in the first INSERT statement are not used when adding the parameter values. All the `comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", .....);` lines use `@id`. Therefore, the *actual id value is never saved to table student*.

The second INSERT has always uses 1 as the value of 'id'. Assuming that 'id' is a primary key, it can only contain unique values. Make the 'id' field an IDENTITY field and then remove it from the INSERT statement. Each time a record is then added to the table it will be given the next number in an ever incrementing sequence.

Corrected Code: http://dotnetfiddle.net/Dr9842